# fetch data from parent model using the foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

How can the user access all client details (client model) when the user checks the invoice details(from invoice model) which has a foreign key

client model

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    clients_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True,)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True )
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True )
```

invoice model

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    clients_name = models.ForeignKey(Clients, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique =True)
    due_date = models.DateField()
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

This is where i get stuck

I have a view to fetch details about the invoice. But now i would the user to also view all client details from client model based on the clients_name (the foreign key)

```
def single_invoice_details(request, slug):
    try:
        invoice_details = Invoice.objects.get(slug=invoice_number)

    except:
        return HttpResponse('cannot be found')
    
    return render(request, 'invoices/invoice_details.html', {'invoice_details': invoice_details})
```

What i tried

```
def single_invoice_details(request, slug):
    try:
        invoice_details = Invoice.objects.get(slug=invoice_number)

    except:
        return HttpResponse('cannot be found')
        clients_details = Clients.objects.filter(clients_name=invoice_details)

    return render(request, 'invoices/invoice_details.html', {'invoice_details': invoice_details,'clients_details':clients_details})
```

Comment: If the client is already set as FK in your invoice, you might try in your django view : invoice_details.client_name to get the related model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out to get the client details you don't need to add anything in the view. Add `invoice_details.client_name.phone_number` or `invoice_details.client_name.email` in the Django template